# Sequence of keys examined search

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree

Suppose that a certain binary search tree has keys that are integers between 1
and 20, and we search for 10. Which sequence below cannot be the sequence
of keys examined?

(a) 20, 5, 15, 8, 12, 9, 10

(b) 1, 12, 10, 16, 14, 15

(c) 5, 13, 7, 10, 8

I don't quite get the question, what I am understanding is which sequence doesnt have 10 , but since every sequence contains 10, doesnt it means every sequence can be examined?

Comment: (a) makes sense because 10 is the last one examined (so stop when you found it);  neither (b) nor (c) makes sense since they continue after finding 10.  Since its nonsense, we can only guess at the intent of the question.  FWIW, my guess is :  as you drill down a binary tree, you should never encounter a key value greater than the last node that you previously took the “less” branch from (nor likewise a key less than where you previously took the “greater” branch).   This rule is broken by just one of the sequences above :)

Comment: @racraman could you give an example? I am still confuse on your statement  "you should never encounter a key value greater than the last node that you previously took the “less” branch from (nor likewise a key less than where you previously took the “greater” branch)." Thanks

Comment: Sure.  Suppose as per the question you are looking for 10.  While drilling down, you encounter the node with key value 5.  Let’s say the Left branch holds the “smaller” values, and the Right branch holds the “larger” numbers.  This means we will take the Right branch - but that also means we should now never encounter any node with a value less than 5.

Comment: @racraman Also I still couldnt see which sequence above broke the rule, as it seems all 3 trees seem to traverse fine, could you point me out? thanks

Comment: @racraman I couldnt figure it out which sequence cannot be examined, could you help me out?

Comment: Can you see why, given a sequence of keys like 8 -> 3 -> 6 , the continued sequence should not contain a 10 ?

Comment: @racraman Cause 10 should be on the right side of 8 since its bigger?

Comment: Exactly.  You just have to follow that logic with those sequences in the question.  8 -> 3 is a DROP in value, so that means that sets the UPPER bound of 8 (ie, nothing should be bigger than 8).  The next step is 3 -> 6, so an INCREASE in value which means that sets the LOWER bound of 3 (ie nothing should be smaller than 3).   Just apply that logic to each step in each of the sequences, and you'll find a number that breaks those bounds.

Comment: thank you ver much  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, (b) and (c) make no sense if 10 is the target, so we'll change the question to just say "searching for a given number".

While drilling down through a Binary Search Tree, we should never encounter keys that are outside the bounds of what we compared previously.

For example, consider :

[image: Binary Search Tree]

(we can also imagine that the tree goes much further down - for example, that the nodes can hold floating point numbers, not just integers).

Suppose we are looking for 7.5, so have drilled down to 7 (and there are further nodes below 7, like 7.1, 7.3, etc .....).

For the remainder of the search, we should never encounter :

a) Any key less than 6 (because we took the right branch at 6)

NOR

b) Any key greater than 8 (because we took the left branch at 8)

Now consider the sequence of keys that we have visited :
8 -> 3 -> 6 -> 7

Notice how the bounds ("less than 6", "greater than 8") are derived from that sequence (eg, from 8 we went lower to 3, so this would mean subsequently encountering a key "greater than 8" should be impossible).

Since this is an assignment, I won't give the answer directly, but I hope this is sufficient detail for you to work it through yourself :)